# Catch the current executed method Eclipse Java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, methods, call

I have an application that was written by another guy and I have to add function there. The code is pretty complex to simply look for a method I need to change. So I wanted to ask if there is a possibility to debug the application and catch on the run what method is currently called,concrete: I want to open a graphical editor in application, add an object in this editor and get the trace of methods that are being executed during adding the object without knowing anything about the application code. Is there any possibility for that? Practically I want to know what methods are executed by JVM

Thank for your help,
Jeff

Comment: see yourkit profiler.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I needed, I owe you one :-) If you should be from Germany just tell me where I can invite you to a beer :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a profiler to get into the code but this won't be easy. Nevertheless, it's crucial to understand the code before working on it. Eclipse offers a broad range of static code analysis tools for this, like call hierarchy, ...

Comment: My problem is, that the code is really pretty complex and I can not ask anyone of the guys that wrote it. Profiler shows me more tahn 10000 called methods on the launch of the application, so it would cost really much time to find the method I am looking for with only analyzing method statically. And as a newbie it is really pretty complicated for me. At the end I found out pretty quickly that to catch the occurence of isDirty flag I need to add a listener to CommanStack (correct meplease if I am wrong) :-)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you've added a comment on Juvanis' comment that yourkit profiler is exactly what you are looking for but in this comment you state that the profiler shows you more than 10000 method calls which is too complicated for you?!